# How to get a named loop variable in ractive.js?

Tags: ractivejs

In Python, iteration gives me a named variable:

```
for cage in cages:
    for animal in cage.animals:
        print("The current cage is",cage)
        print("the current animal is",animal)
```

In Ractive templates, I don't appear to be able to do this.

```
{{#cages}}
    {{#animals}}
         The current animal is {{.}} or {{this}},
         but I don't know how to refer to the current cage,
         i.e. the outer loop variable

         I would like to be able to say {{cage}} has an {{animal}}
    {{/animals}}
{{/cages}}
```

Is there a syntax I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 5):

I've wondered about whether we should add an `{{#each cage in cages}}` or `{{#each cages as cage}}` syntax to handle cases like these. In lieu of that, mknecht's answer is totally valid, and something I often use myself; an alternative is to create an index reference like so:

```html
{{#each cages :c}}
  {{#each animals}}
    The current animal is {{this}}, the current cage
    is {{cages[c]}}
  {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

The difference with this method is that two-way binding will still work (though it doesn't sound like that's an issue in this case.)

Comment: I would very much like to see `{{#each cage in cages}}` or `{{#each cages as cage}}`, that would make writing nested loops much easier.

Answer (score 4):

There is no explicit syntax, afaik, but you may (mis)use [aliases](http://docs.ractivejs.org/latest/mustaches#aliasing) for that: You create a new context, which renames `.` to `cage`, for example. It would look like so:

```
{{#cages}} {{# {cage: .} }}
  {{ cage.name }}
{{/}}{{/cages}}
```

A complete version is [on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nntdv5uy/3/)

*Mis*use because in Ractive, you usually work on the *properties* of the current context object without naming the context object itself. This works fine in the nested case, too. Therefore, there is no syntax for this.

Where aliases do make sense: name-shadowing. If you need to access a cage-property with the same name as an animal-property *in the inner loop*, then aliases come into play. Both is [demonstrated in another fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g26an0md/1/)